# How to determine program crash

Tags: c, linux

How i can determine the running program is crashed or terminated successfully?

I run the program with `system('exe')`, and i have the source code of `'exe'` in `C`?

I prefer a solution like adding some code  to `'exe's` code. like `atexit(someFunction)` - but `atexit` is not working on `exceptions`-.

I'm using Linux.

Comment: if you launch your program with exec family you can get the return code with function of wait family

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`system` returns:

> The value returned is -1 on error (e.g., fork(2) failed), and the
>   return status of the command otherwise.  This latter return status is
>   in the format specified in wait(2).  Thus, the exit code of the
>   command will be WEXITSTATUS(status).  In case /bin/sh could not be
>   executed, the exit status will be that of a command that does
>   exit(127).

Therefor store the return value of the `system` call and then check the return value. If your "exe" returns a success code you will know it has terminated successfully, or else if specific error code is returned by your code then you will know what error was that, else you can assume the code crashed.

As Ingo Leonhardt told in the comment, you can check for signals using the `WTERMSIG()` and `WIFSIGNALED()` macros to test the returned value by `system` function call to check if a signal occurred and if yes then which one.

Here is a quick example:

**bad.c** Will segfault.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  char *p = "Hello";

  p[1] = 'X';

  return 1;
}
```

**system.c** executes bad.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main (void)
{
  int retval;

  retval = system ("./bad");
  if (!WIFSIGNALED(retval))
  {
    printf ("Process completed successfully\n");
  }
  else
  {
    switch (WTERMSIG(retval))
    {
      case SIGINT: printf ("SIGINT\n");
                 break;
      case SIGSEGV: printf ("SIGSEGV\n");
                  break;

      case SIGQUIT: printf ("SIGQUIT\n");
                  break;
    }
  }
  printf ("EXIT STATUS: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(retval));
  return 0;
}
```

But the recommended process is to use `exec` family and `wait` family in these cases. These will give you much better control on the executing of the process.

See:

- man 3 exec
- man 3 wait
- http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html

Comment: And what if the program crashes? Then it might return anything, including a "success" value.

Comment: Yes it can, that is why I won't use it. The description I gave is a rough attempt to detect a crash.

Comment: When the program crashes, WIFSIGNALED() should return TRUE and WTERMSIG() gives you a signal number, e.g. SIGSEGV